# Why float-right, float-left don't working properly?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4

This is snippet code.

```
<div class="row col-xs-12">
<a *ngFor="let rec of recipe "href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix">
    <div class="float-left">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{rec.name}}</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">{{rec.description}}</p>
    </div>
    <span class="float-right">
        <img [src]="rec.imagePath" alt="{{rec.name}}" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 50px;">
    </span>
</a>
<app-recipe-item></app-recipe-item>
```

I wonder why float-right don't align image to right side. If i use insetead pull-right it's working.I have read that bootstrap 4 we should float rather than pull.

Comment: Span is a inline element.. so try to change that to DIV

Comment: @Hardy i change to DIV but still the same

Comment: you have `<div class="row col-xs-12">` without ending tag and also row and col should not be in same element..

Comment: @Hardy I have </div> tag only don't paste it.

Comment: @Hardy I also delete .col-xs-12 but not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted list-group-item, list-group-item-heading , list-group-item-text and it worked.

```
<a href="#" class="clearfix" *ngFor="let recipe of recipes">
        <div class="float-left">
            <h4>{{ recipe.name }}</h4>
            <p>{{ recipe.description }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the xs-12 specifier in the col class.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix" *ngFor="let recipe of recipes">
      <div class="float-left">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ recipe.name }}</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ recipe.description }}</p>
      </div>
      <span class="float-right">
        <img
          [src]="recipe.imagePath"
          alt="{{ recipe.name }}"
          class="img-responsive"
          style="max-height: 50px"
        />
      </span>
    </a>
    <app-recipe-item></app-recipe-item>
  </div>
</div>
```